# Drupal 7 - Ajax form in modal window

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I try to create modal window with form (from page /node/add/page).
Try this

```
hook_menu() {items['mypath']=...} + callback (where echo drupal_render($form); exit();)
```

//form has many elements from different modules (node + inline register)

Next

- get rendered form via ajax (form has action 'mypath')
- plug jquery.form.js to the form

Submit

Server returns full page and i'm sure that new page material doesn't save even if i change action to '/node/add/page' instead of 'mypath'

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you doing from your description. A better description could possibly yield better answers.

One possible problem could be that the form needs to be loaded on the page the it is submitted on. This is required for the validate and submit handlers to be processed.

Comment: the question is how send form via jquery.form?